# Manifest references file 'Band.dll' which is not part of the payload

Tags: release, uwp, microsoft-band

I'm developing and app for UWP using Microsoft Band. Eveything works fine, but when set to `Release` mode, I've got an error: `Manifest references file 'Band.dll' which is not part of the payload.`. In `Debug` everything is OK, app can be deployed to device and it's connecting to the my Band. In my `Package.appxmanifest` I have enabled `bluetooth` and `proximity` capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix available the link and install instructions are in this thread

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73f2d56d-9e8e-4b57-bcfa-0a972dfd75d7/update-11-generating-store-associated-package-fails-for-a-uwp-application-with-a-winrt-component?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues